# How to update rows based on previous records in SQL?

Tags: sql

I have a table as following:

```
ID  MARKET
2   INDIV
2   CPEINT
2   INDIV
2   INDIV
2   INDIV
2   INDIV
2   INDIV
5   INDIV
5   INDIV
5   CPEINT
5   INDIV
5   INDIV
5   INDIV
5   INDIV
5   INDIV
5   INDIV
```

What I want is to update the records in MARKET column based on the previous rows in ID and MARKET. If previous MARKET is CPEINT and the current ID is the same as previous ID, then replace the current MARKET as CPEINT. The output I am looking for will be:

```
ID  MARKET
2   INDIV
2   CPEINT
2   CPEINT
2   CPEINT
2   CPEINT
2   CPEINT
2   CPEINT
5   INDIV
5   INDIV
5   CPEINT
5   CPEINT
5   CPEINT
5   CPEINT
5   CPEINT
5   CPEINT
5   CPEINT
```

Can I use something like MERGE or UPDATE to do this?

Many thanks!

Comment: Unless you have other columns (e.g. primary key) in that table, then the concept of "previous row" is ambiguous (Oracle) or non-existent (SQL Server)

Comment: Which is your database?

Comment: hi techdo, the first table is my database

Comment: Is it SQL Server or MySQL or Oracle?

Comment: it is SQL Server 2008, thx

Comment: Please try the added answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try query for SQL server:

```
;with T as(
    select 
        ROW_NUMBER() over (order by ID) RNum, * 
    From 
        YourTable)
    update c set MARKET='CPEINT'
    from T c join
    (select a.RNum, a.ID
    From T a LEFT JOIN T b on a.RNum=b.RNum+1
    where a.ID=b.ID and b.MARKET='CPEINT')x on c.RNum>=x.RNum AND c.ID=x.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not satisfy your requirements.

```
update yourtable
set market = 'CPEINT'
where id in 
(select id 
from yourtable
where market = 'CPEINT')
and market = 'MARKET'
```

Comment: It won't. Your query won't leave any INDIV's